# Longest relation between two strings

Tags: c, string

I am trying to find the maximum overlap between two strings without using any advanced functions or pointers but I am only able to find the overlap in the beginning of the strings using this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char string1[256], string2[256];
    int len = 0;

    printf ("Enter string1");
    fgets (string1, sizeof (string1), stdin);

    printf ("Enter string2");
    fgets (string2, sizeof (string2), stdin);

    while (strncmp (string1, string2, len) == 0 && len < strlen (string1)) {
        len = len + 1;
    }
    printf ("%d\n", len - 1);
    printf (strcat (string1, string2));

    return 0;
}
```

For example: If we enter "axyz" and "343axyz" it should get an output equal to 4. However, if I enter the similarity in the beginning "This is ax" and "This isas" is giving me the correct output 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two `for`/`while` loops to compute the maximum overlap.

1. In first loop, you step through the elements of the first string.
2. In the second loop, you step through the elements of the second string.
3. Keep track of the overall maximum overlap in a variable.
   Compare the maximum overlap between the part of the first string and part of the second string as the inner function of the two loops.

Something like:

```
int maxOverlap = 0;
for (char* s1 = string1; *s1 != '\0'; ++s1)
{
   for (char* s2 = string2; *s2 != '\0'; ++s2)
   {
      int overlap = 0;
      while (s1[overlap] != '\0' && s1[overlap] == s2[overlap])
      {
         ++overlap;
      }
      if ( maxOverlap < overlap )
      {
         maxOverlap = overlap;
      }
   }
}
```